# How to select an older compiler in Microsoft Visual C++ 2019?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-version

As written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33122650/compiling-with-microsoft-visual-c-2013-under-visual-studio-2015), under "Project Settings" I should be able to specify the compiler to be used for the current project. However, I cannot find this menu entry in Visual Studio 2019.

I have both Visual C++ 2019 and 2013, and would like to use the new IDE with the old compiler. How can I do it?

Is it possible to do it with the "Community" editions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are the official instructions, taken from [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/how-to-modify-the-target-framework-and-platform-toolset?view=vs-2019):

> 1. In Visual Studio, in Solution Explorer, open the shortcut menu for
>      your project (**not** for your solution) and then choose Properties to
>      open your project Property Pages dialog box.
> 2. In the Property Pages dialog box, open the Configuration drop-down
>      list and then select All Configurations.
> 3. In the left pane of the dialog box, expand Configuration Properties
>      and then select General.
> 4. In the right pane, select Platform Toolset and then select the
>      toolset you want from the drop-down list. For example, if you have
>      installed the Visual Studio 2010 toolset, select Visual Studio 2010
>      (v100) to use it for your project.
> 5. Choose the OK button.

---

You can see a screenshot of my window below:

[image: screenshot of config window]

Comment: The only option I can see related to the compiler is the "C++ Language Standard", which can be set to C++14, C++17 and C++Latest. I cannot see anything about the possibility to specify a different compiler.

Comment: @Pietro When you go into your Visual Studio Installer, select Modify, and go to the Individual Components tab, do you see anything other than the latest MSVC option selected in the Compiler section?

Comment: The MSVC versions I ticked are "MSCV v140 - VS 2015 C++ build tools (v14.00)" and "MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools (v14.20)". So I should have at least two compilers to choose from...

Comment: @Pietro See my edits to get the updated solution. Looks like the original pages I linked were updated recently, but did not apply to the most recent version of VS.